# Adding multiple rows in rhandsontable via context menu

Tags: javascript, r, handsontable, rhandsontable

I'm using the `rhandsontable`package and would like to add a context menu option for adding multiple rows to the `handsontable` produced. I've tried to adapt [this](http://jsfiddle.net/handsoncode/n46jyrq4/) example into my R equivalent with no luck. I believe my `javascript` is the issue but don't have the experience to spot what's wrong.

How can I add a custom context menu item for adding multiple rows? Thanks in advance.

**Reprex**

```
library(rhandsontable)

iris %>%
  head(5) %>%
  rhandsontable() %>%
  hot_context_menu(customOpts =
                     list(
                       name = "Add 5 rows at the top",
                       callback = htmlwidgets::JS(
                         "function (key, options) {
                              this.alter('insert_row', 1, 5);
                              this.render();
                              }"
                       )
                     ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and solved it by designating the option that will be customized by adding `insert_row = list` inside `list` :

```
library(rhandsontable)

iris %>%
  head(5) %>%
  rhandsontable() %>%
  
  
  hot_context_menu(customOpts =
                     
                     list(
                       insert_row = list(
                         name = "Add 5 rows at the top",
                         callback = htmlwidgets::JS(
                           "function (key, options) {
                              this.alter('insert_row',0, 5);
                              this.render();
                              }"
                         )
                       )
                     ))
```

I also changed `this.alter('insert_row',1, 5);`as in your example to `this.alter('insert_row',0, 5);`. That is because if you have it as in your example, the new 5 rows are added below the first row, whereas as in my example the new rows will be created at the top of the table. To get the rows below, use `this.alter('insert_row',[0], 5);`